# Python: Why does this array get 'gridwidth' amount of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

```
for i in range(0, gridwidth):
        row.append(random.randint(0, 1))
```

Since array indexing starts at 0, I assumed that the `row` array would have `gridwidth + 1` indices, since it would count every integer up to and including `gridwidth`, but also 0. However, after checking the array, it contains only `gridwidth` amount of indices. While it doesn't hinder my code, I'm curious as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While it doesn't hinder my code, I'm curious as to why this is happening.

Well, you made the following assumption:

> since it would count every integer up to and including gridwidth, but also 0.

Did you try *testing* that assumption?

```
for i in range(0, gridwidth):
    print(i)
```

Notice that the value of `gridwidth` is *not* printed.

Or you could have tried reading the documentation:

```
>>> help(range)
Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive) |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

The reason it happens this way is because that is how `range` is defined to work.

The motivation for defining `range` that way is because that's what programmers are accustomed to - because in older languages that make you index into arrays in their loops (instead of just getting the items directly) it's [easier to avoid logical errors](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really curious, try this:

```
print(len(range(0, gridwidth)))
```

Then, have a look at [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) documentation,

> the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop

The `range(0, gridwidth)` (range is a class of immutable iterable objects) will return a sequence having numbers from 0 to (gridwidth - 1).

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop will iterate `gridwidth`  times so your `row` will have `gridwidth` elements appended,  also you may pay attention to the built-in class [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) who is giving you the number of iterations for your `for` loop, the range will  give you numbers between `0` and `gridwidth - 1`

also, `range(0, gridwidth)` it is the same with `range(gridwidth)` the start point  for `range` is by default `0`

if you want to achieve `gridwidth + 1` elements appended to your `row` you may use:

```
for i in range(gridwidth + 1):
        row.append(random.randint(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `range` function is closed on left side and open on right side. What that means is it will include `0` but not `gridwidth`. The mathematical notation is [0, gridwidth). So your iteration is from `0 to`gridwidth-1`making array contain`gridwidth` elements.